# How to output PDO query result in JSON

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm trying to output the content of my DB in JSON but I always get `false`.

```
$query = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM tab');
$result = $query->fetchAll();
$result = json_encode($result);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What's the value of `$result` before encoding?

Comment: It returns an array like this : http://i.imgur.com/HJDcGuv.png